# trying to copy all the elements of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> messages;
typedef std::vector<std::string> addMessage;
messages st;
addMessage additionlMsgs;
```

when the user inputs a string i then split that string by a certain character which is then splitted into **st**

i want to copy that vector over to **additionalMsgs** at some point but i get a run time error i cannot see why.

i try to copy it over as follows

```
 copy(st.begin(), st.end(), additionlMsgs.begin());
```

can you see anything that is incorrect?

Thanks
Shamari

Comment: What is the runtime error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::copy(st.begin(), st.end(), std::back_inserter(additionlMsgs));
```

That'll *append* to `additionlMsgs`. If you wish to *overwrite* its contents, you might want to use:

```
additionlMsgs = st;
```

The code you have right now never adds new elements to `additionlMsgs`; it simply overwrites existing ones without performing any bounds checking. If `additionlMsgs` is too short, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: If he wants to overwrite existing ones, why not: `additionlMsgs = st;` ?

Comment: @Rob: Of course, thanks (what was I thinking?) Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to append:

```
additionlMsgs.insert(additionlMsgs.end(), st.begin(), st.end());
```

If you want to overwrite:

```
additionlMsgs = st;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using resize is probably a better option in this case.

```
additionlMsgs.resize(messages.size());
copy(st.begin(), st.end(), additionlMsgs.begin());
```

This is because additionalMsgs only gets reallocated once, as opposed to multiple times when back_inserter is used.